# nightmare.js trying to click on link based on anchor text

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to use nightmare, in node js to click on links based on the text inside the anchor text of the link.

Here's some example code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({show: true})

    nightmare
    .goto('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
    .inject('js', 'C:/users/myname/desktop/nodejs/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    .wait(500)
var selector = 'a';
nightmare
  .evaluate(function (selector) {
    // now we're executing inside the browser scope.
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
   }, selector) // <-- that's how you pass parameters from Node scope to browser scope
  .end()
  .then(function(result) {
   console.log(result)
  })
```

I'm really unclear on why the inner text of all  tags are not returning? I thought I could maybe do an if statement in the .evalution method, so that it would restrict the link to be clicked on to "English" for instance.

Any idea how to click on links based on the link text?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to select a DOM element solely on what it contains.  You'll either need to select all of the anchors (like you're doing now) and filter to what you want based on `innerText` then issue click events directly, or you could inject jQuery and use `:contains` and `$.click()` to issue the click.

Also, if you want *all* of the text from the tags, you'll likely want to use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

As an example to get all of the text:

```
.evaluate(function (selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    .map(element => element.innerText);
}, selector)
```